# How to calculate with values from textboxes, progressbar and performancecounters? C#

Tags: c#, textbox, calculator, performancecounter, divide

I have a performance calculator, and that gives me the memory in KB.
But i want to divide the Value with 1000, so I didnt get it longer in KB, but in MB.

I have tried this:

```
    progressBar9.Value = (int)(performanceCounter9.NextValue());
    progressBar9.Value.ToString() / 1000;
    textBox5.Text = "Max. memory: " + progressBar9.Value.ToString() + " KB";
```

I have never earlier calculated with C# so I am a little bit newbie with calculating in C#

Comment: Currently you're trying to divide a string by 1000 - and then do nothing with it (the middle line). It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: I didn't know what you mean. i already said I'm newbie, so can you give me an example of a working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to show in your `progressBar9` (KB or MB) you could use something like:

> progressBar9.Value = (int)(performanceCounter9.NextValue()/1024); //value in MB
>
> textBox5.Text = "Max. memory: " + progressBar9.Value.ToString() + " MB";

or

> progressBar9.Value = (int)(performanceCounter9.NextValue()); //value in KB
>
> textBox5.Text = "Max. memory: " + (progressBar9.Value/1024).ToString() + " MB";

Comment: Thanks! the last one was what I want.

Comment: And how can I do then (progressbar9.value / 1024) - prograssbar3.value

other explain: progressbar9 / 1024 and then the answer from that - progressbar3.value

Comment: @ThijmenMinecraft, I don't know if I understand what you mean here, do you want something like: `textBox6.Text = "Available memory: " + ((progressBar9.Value/1024)-prograssbar3.value).ToString() + " MB";` ?

Comment: Yes, much thanks! that is exactly what I mean! Thanks for answering my question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
        pb.Value = (int)(pb.NextValue());
        decimal memory = Convert.ToDecimal(pb.Value) / 1024;
        textBox5.Text = "Max. memory: " + memory.ToString() + " KB";
```

Converting it to decimal will let your application be able to use decimals instead of just whole numbers.

There is also 1024 kb in a mb, not 1000.